# Why this code resulted a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i am writing a simple simulator of spilling eggs in а pan with the flood fill algorithm in C. So the pan is a char matrix, and with '#' are his walls,'.' means that the place is empty and 'O' that it has a egg that will spill. 

That is an example of what that program should do.

```
10 10
..##......
.#O.#.....
.#..#..#..
..##..#.#.
.......#..
..#####...
..#...#...
..#...##..
...##..#..
....####..
⇨

..##......
.#OO#.....
.#OO#..#..
..##..#.#.
.......#..
..#####...
..#***#...
..#***##..
...##**#..
....####..
```

i have written that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void food_fill(int,int,char [1000][1000],int,int,char);
int main(){
    int row,col,rows,cols;
    scanf("%d %d",&rows,&cols);
    getchar();
    char matrix [rows][cols];
    for(row = 0;row < rows;row++){
        for(col = 0;col < cols;col++){
            scanf("%c",&matrix[row][col]);

        }
        getchar();
    }
    int foodX=0,foodY=0;
    char foodChar='s';
    for(row=0;row<rows;row++){
        for(col = 0;col < cols;col++){
            if(matrix[row][col] == 'O'){
                foodX = row;
                foodY = col;
                foodChar = matrix[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    food_fill(rows,cols,matrix,foodX,foodY,foodChar);
    for(row = 0;row < rows;row++){
        for(col = 0;col <cols;col++){
            printf("%c",matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
void food_fill(int rows,int cols,char matrix[rows][cols],int foodX,int foodY,char foodChar){
    int r=rows,c=cols;
    if(matrix[foodX][foodY] == '#')return;
    if(foodX < 0 || foodX >= rows || foodY < 0 || foodY >= cols)return;
    matrix[foodX][foodY] = foodChar;
    food_fill(r,c,matrix,foodX+1,foodY,foodChar);
    food_fill(r,c,matrix,foodX-1,foodY,foodChar);
    food_fill(r,c,matrix,foodX,foodY+1,foodChar);
    food_fill(r,c,matrix,foodX,foodY-1,foodChar);

}
```

It is not completed yet but the food_fill() function resulted in segmentation fault and i don't know why.

Comment: Now's the time to learn how to use a debugger to find the answers to such questions yourself. IMO it doesn't make for interesting questions, nor a good learning experience, to just ask people on the internet to analyse a heap of code every time and tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Run your program under `valgrind` and see what it says. Make sure to compile with debug info; then it will porbably  tell you the exact file and line where the fault occurs.

Comment: `food_fill()` accesses `matrix[foodX][foodY]` BEFORE checking if `foodX` and `foodY` are valid indices.   It therefore has undefined behaviour.   Worse, the function is infinitely recursive  for some valid indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(matrix[foodX][foodY] == '#')return;
if(foodX < 0 || foodX >= rows || foodY < 0 || foodY >= cols)return;
```

Order is wrong. As a result you are accessing invalid indices. Giving you segmentation fault. Correct one would be

```
if(foodX < 0 || foodX >= rows || foodY < 0 || foodY >= cols)return;
if(matrix[foodX][foodY] == '#')return;
```

Also there are bugs on many levels.

You are having an infinite loop due to repetitive similar calls.

```
int dx[]={1,0,-1,0};
int dy[]={0,1,0,-1};

void food_fill(int rows,int cols,char matrix[][cols],int foodX,int foodY,char foodChar){

    matrix[foodX][foodY] = foodChar;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if( foodX+dx[i]>=0 && foodX+dx[i]<rows && foodY+dy[i] >=0 && foodY+dy[i]<cols && matrix[foodX+dx[i]][foodY+dy[i]] != '#' && matrix[foodX+dx[i]][foodY+dy[i]]!=foodChar){
            food_fill(rows,cols,matrix,foodX+dx[i],foodY+dy[i],foodChar);
        }
    }
}
```

The main condition change is

```
  if( foodX+dx[i]>=0 && foodX+dx[i]<rows && foodY+dy[i] >=0 && foodY+dy[i]<cols && matrix[foodX+dx[i]][foodY+dy[i]] != '#' && matrix[foodX+dx[i]][foodY+dy[i]]!=foodChar){
```